# Непонятная ошибка Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Пытаюсь сделать гиперказуалку, но столкнулся с элементарной проблемой. Моя идея в том, что когда игрок или куб касается другого куба, игрок поднимается на 1.5f вверх и дальше движется вместе с этис кубом, так как он становится дочерним, когда сам игрок это делает не возникает никаких проблем, но если куба касается другой куб то игра ломается, я не понимаю почему.
Добрые люди подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так((

[image: Код Игрока]

[image: Код town.cs]

Вот сама ошибка:

Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'Cube (1)(Clone)').
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
town:OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider) (at Assets/town.cs:24)

Comment: Вот ссылка на видео

https://youtu.be/4GcIpFa5Mxw

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Убедитесь что в скрипте в качестве player стоит объект находящийся на сцене(Из Hierarchy) а не pfelab  находящийся в Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас объекты генерируются процедурно поэтому в tower.cs в `void Start()` нужно добавить `player = GameObject.Find("ИМЯ ОБЪЕКТА ИГРОКА");` в вашем случае `ИМЯ ОБЪЕКТА ИГРОКА` это `realnormalguy@Goofy Running`:

```cs
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("realnormalguy@Goofy Running");
}
```

Comment: Действительно заработало, спасибо большое)